# FLAT JSON to HIERARCHY JSON

Tags: node.js

I am getting JSON in the following format:

```
[
        {
            "PatientId": 1,
            "FirstName": "Emma",
            "LastName": "Williams",
            "Sex": "Female",
            "DOB": "1982-06-17T18:30:00.000Z",
            "ProgramName": "UHC_ACO_1",
            "ScheduledDate": "2018-09-18T18:30:00.000Z",
            "vfirstname": "Mia",
            "vlastname": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "PatientId": 1,
            "FirstName": "Emma",
            "LastName": "Williams",
            "Sex": "Female",
            "DOB": "1982-06-17T18:30:00.000Z",
            "ProgramName": "UHC_ACO_2",
            "ScheduledDate": "2018-09-18T18:30:00.000Z",
            "vfirstname": "Mia",
            "vlastname": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "PatientId": 2,
            "FirstName": "James",
            "LastName": "Smith",
            "Sex": "Male",
            "DOB": "2009-06-19T18:30:00.000Z",
            "ProgramName": "UHC_ACO_1",
            "ScheduledDate": null,
            "vfirstname": null,
            "vlastname": null
        }
    ]
```

But really I want the following format

```
[
         {
            "PatientId": 1,
            "FirstName": "Emma",
            "LastName": "Williams",
            "Sex": "Female",
            "DOB": "1982-06-17T18:30:00.000Z",
            "ProgramId":[
                        {
                            "ProgramName": "UHC_ACO_1",
                            "ScheduledDate": "2018-09-18T18:30:00.000Z",
                            "vfirstname": "Mia",
                            "vlastname": "Smith"
                        },
                        {
                            "ProgramName": "UHC_ACO_2",
                            "ScheduledDate": "2018-09-18T18:30:00.000Z",
                            "vfirstname": "Mia",
                            "vlastname": "Smith"
                        }
                        ]
        },

        {
            "PatientId": 2,
            "FirstName": "James",
            "LastName": "Smith",
            "Sex": "Male",
            "DOB": "2009-06-19T18:30:00.000Z",
            "ProgramId":[
                         {
                            "ProgramName": "UHC_ACO_1",
                            "ScheduledDate": null,
                            "vfirstname": null,
                            "vlastname": null
                        }
                        ]
        }
       ]
```

I saw many examples, where its looping on parents,children, to get the tree structure.

But I don't want anything to be hard coded, as the json format might change.

What I want a generic method.

I am using nodejs, express framework in my code.

Comment: I'm not sure what your definition of "hard coded" entails, but you'll have to use looping involving parents/children to create the tree structure you require. If the structure changes such that the code no longer functions, you'll have to update it. That's just how it works.

Comment: Basically what I do, is to dump the rows[ ], that is returned by the call back connection.query in response string, do json stringyfy, and send it to front end. But now I dont want to manipulate this rows []

Answer (score -1):

Lodash solves the issue without hard coding any thing

Comment: GENIUS PEOPLE WHO ARE DOWN VOTING, PLEASE TELL ME A BETTER WAY TO DO IT.